# Настройка блокировки системы при закрытии крышки ноутбука

Tags: windows

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить ноут на Windows 10 так, чтобы при закрытии крышки происходила просто блокировка системы (как Win+L). Гибернация и сон не подходит!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это в параметрах электропитания настраивается

Answer (score 5):

Открываем Пуск/Параметры/Система/Питание и спящий режим/Дополнительные параметры питания.  Слева видим "Действия при закрытии крышки":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жмём мышкой туда. Настраиваем то, что желаем, а именно - Действие не требуется. Указываем, чтобы спрашивал пароль. Всё.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Альтернативный, более быстрый вариант:**

Жмём Win+R, вводим "control.exe powercfg.cpl,,3", получаем окно, в котором сразу идём в настройку "Кнопки питания и крышка".

**Не могу удержаться от хардкорного варианта :)**

В powershell выполняем скрипт, который сразу устанавливает то, что нам нужно (только блокировку системы при закрытии крышки):

```
$class = ([wmi] '\root\cimv2\power:Win32_PowerSettingDataIndex.InstanceID="Microsoft:PowerSettingDataIndex\\{8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c}\\DC\\{5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936}"')
$class.SettingIndexValue = 0
$class.Put()
```

Comment: Вы всё на powershell'е делаете? :)

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Нет :) В данном случае это был небольшой вызов. Но, в целом, powershell может стать очень мощной системой управления, особенно, если строить на нём многоуровневые меню, позволяющие быстро достигнуть нужной цели в контроле/управлении/проверки системы. Но, возможно, я - просто старый олдфаг, которому нравится консоль :)

Comment: *"Указываем, чтобы спрашивал пароль. Всё."* - на картинке же нет такой опции

Comment: @user7860670  Неужели? "Парольная защита при пробуждении/Запрашивать пароль (рекомендуется)"

Comment: Вот я про это и говорю. Перечитайте еще раз: **при пробуждении**. Теперь перечитайте вопрос: **Гибернация и сон не подходит!**